# Flash presentation won't load on my web page

Tags: html, flash, asp-classic, embed

I found this solution over several places, regarding embeding a flash animation on my webpage but when I tried it, in my page only a white rectangle opens but the flash animation never plays.

I'm totally new for this Flash animations and object embeding thing so don't have any idea how to proceed.

```
 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" width="1000" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="birthdayAS2.swf">
    <embed href="birthdayAS2.swf" width="1000" height="600" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
 </object>
```

Greetings

Comment: The href path is relative to the webpage it is located in, does the directory your webpage is in contain the `birthdayAS2.swf` file?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the file "birthdayAS2.swf" is in the same directory as of the file that you have mentioned above ?

Also please check whether your browser supports flash or not.

Answer (score 0):

This means that flash player is loading.  It also means that it cannot find the file.

Comment: Maybe the presentation is site locked to a url?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researching and testing I came up with this code:

```
   <div id="flashcontent" align="center">
       <object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="birthdayAS2.swf"    classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash   /swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="700" height="600" align="middle">
           <param name="movie" value="birthdayAS2.swf">
           <param name="quality" value="high" />
           <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
           <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
           <embed src="birthdayAS2.swf" quality="high"    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-   flash" width="700" height="600" bgcolor="#000000" wmode="transparent"  > </embed>
       </object>
   </div>
```